# Can't create ERD from Microsoft SQL Server running on Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I'm running the latest versoion of the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022` Docker image. To connect to my database I used the SQL Server Management Studio (version 18.12.1). After creating my DB containing some tables I wanted to generate an ERD and stumbled uppon this error:
[ssms error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0dT.png)

I looked it up online and the only fix I found was updating SSMS but since im allready running the latest version, that wasn't a fix.

Comment: What version are you running, exactly? The "latest version" is not necessarily what you think.

Comment: BTW, SSMS Database Diagrams are **not** Entity-Relationship-Diagrams: this is because an entity is a business/domain concern and does not necessarily have to have a bijective correspondance to a single table (i.e. entities can span multiple tables, and vice-versa, especially inside a fully normalized database), ER diagrams are a (slightly) higher level than table diagrams.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.